# Jenkins Script Pipeline sonar Integration

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

i'd like to start a Sonar project analysis with Jenkins 2.x Groovy Script Build Pipeline.

I have sonar configured in Maven so thats no big deal:

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${javaHome}", "PATH + MAVEN=${mavenHome}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin", "MAVEN_OPTS=${mavenOpts}"]) {
        sh 'mvn -B sonar:sonar'
}
```

But how can i get results from sonar ? Or even better how can i determine if a quality gate was achived so that i can stop the  build-pipeline.

The build breaker concept is obsolet since some versione of sonar, as far as i know. Or how would you handle this.

I still think it would be a good idea to stop/pause a build pipeline if the underlying code of a project is too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is ideal, but I'm getting the status from the SonarQube api with a request (which you can do with the HttpRequest plugin).

```
def response = httpRequest 'https://SONAR_USER:SONAR_PASSWORD@SONAR_URL/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=PROJECT_KEY'
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response.content)
if (result.projectStatus.status == "ERROR") {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
```

Comment: Tried it and got this: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'httpRequest' found

Comment: @Lee You neet to install the HttpRequest plugin.

Comment: I don't think this is a very clean answer, but it is the only thing I found that actually works, so thank you!